# Google Sheets Conditional formatting autofill?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have the following conditional formatting

`=EQ(VALUE(RIGHT(Y2;1));ISOWEEKNUM(NOW())`

I want to be able to auto fill this formatting to the other columns so the 'Z' column formula would look like this:

`=EQ(VALUE(RIGHT(Z2;1));ISOWEEKNUM(NOW())`

Answer (score 2):

Autofill is not necessary for conditional formatting. You just need to change the area where the formula will apply (this formula is available for the top left cell and will automatically apply to all others in the area)

Comment: the problem is that in the Y column i want to conditional formatting based on the Y2 value 

On the Z column I want to conditional format based on the value of Z2 etc. etc. etc.

Comment: select Y2:Z2 with the same formula, as I said the formula apply to the top left of the area and will populate the remaining cells of the area. If you don't use $ (as $Y2) you will use Z2 in the formula for Z column